# Xcode Archive Error on properties

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, archive

I get  errors on each @synthetize line when I attempt to archive the project. 
!Synthetize property 'lastUpdateDate must either be named the same as a compatible ivar or must explicitly name an ivar'
Same errors on the 2 other variables which are declared as follows :
In Test.h :

```
@interface Test : NSObject {

}

@property(readonly) NSString *lastUpdateDate;
@property(readonly) NSArray *overview;
@property(readonly) NSArray *userPreferences;
```

In test.m :

```
@synthesize lastUpdateDate; ! Synthetise property must be either etc...
@synthesize overview; ! Synthetise property must be either etc...
@synthesize userPreferences; ! Synthetise property must be either etc...
```

I have no errors when I run in debug mode but only when I use Archive.
I checked the project settings (target is modern runtime 10.5 and not legacy runtime).
Help will be very much appreciated as I have no workaround
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared the ivars....

```
@interface Test : NSObject {
    NSString *lastUpdateDate;
    NSArray *overview;
    NSArray *userPreferences
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Errors are fixed. I still have 2 warnings that I can fix. Archive does not appear in organizer (I checked it in the scheme) : is it because of the warnings ?

Comment: What warnings do you have left?

Comment: I have 4 identical warnings on localized.strings :

Comment: The specified input encoding is Unicode (UTF-8), but file contents appear to be Unicode (UTF-16); treating as Unicode (UTF-16).

Comment: I noticed that the Installation Directory in the build settings is (NSHome)/Applications which does not exist. I changed it to (NSHome) but the archive does not appear in organizer

Comment: Problem fixed after a few hours on bind settings!!. Thanks a lot

Comment: @philippehenri how you fix this error "The specified input encoding is Unicode (UTF-8), but file contents appear to be Unicode (UTF-16); treating as Unicode (UTF-16)"?

Comment: Hello,
Sorry but I didn't keep track of what I did in the bindings setup and don't remember